# Holding number of leaves under node in AVL tree

Tags: c++, c, tree, avl-tree

Hello I've got a question. How to hold in every node, number of leaves under it? And how to efficiently update it(during inserting and removing). I can't figure it out. Ty for help. Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct AVLNode
{
    AVLNode * up;
    AVLNode * left;
    AVLNode * right;
    int key;
    int leaves;
    long long data;
    int bf;
};

// Rotacja RR
//-----------
void RR(AVLNode * & root, AVLNode * A)
{
    AVLNode * B = A->right, * p = A->up;

    A->right = B->left;
    if(A->right) A->right->up = A;

    B->left = A;
    B->up = p;
    A->up = B;

    if(p)
    {
        if(p->left == A) p->left = B;
        else p->right = B;
    }
    else root = B;

    if(B->bf == -1) A->bf = B->bf = 0;
    else
    {
        A->bf = -1;
        B->bf = 1;
    }

    if(!A->left && !A->right){
        while(A->up){
            A->up->leaves++;
            A = A->up;
        }
    }
}

// Rotacja LL
//-----------
void LL(AVLNode * & root, AVLNode * A)
{
    AVLNode * B = A->left, * p = A->up;

    A->left = B->right;
    if(A->left) A->left->up = A;

    B->right = A;
    B->up = p;
    A->up = B;

    if(p)
    {
        if(p->left == A) p->left = B;
        else p->right = B;
    }
    else root = B;

    if(B->bf == 1) A->bf = B->bf = 0;
    else
    {
        A->bf = 1;
        B->bf = -1;
    }
}

// Rotacja RL
//-----------
void RL(AVLNode * & root, AVLNode * A)
{
    AVLNode * B = A->right, * C = B->left, * p  = A->up;

    B->left = C->right;
    if(B->left) B->left->up = B;

    A->right = C->left;
    if(A->right) A->right->up = A;

    C->left = A;
    C->right = B;
    A->up = B->up = C;
    C->up = p;

    if(p)
    {
        if(p->left == A) p->left = C;
        else p->right = C;
    }
    else root = C;

    if(C->bf == -1) A->bf =  1;
    else A->bf = 0;
    if(C->bf ==  1) B->bf = -1;
    else B->bf = 0;

    C->bf = 0;
}

// Rotacja LR
//-----------
void LR(AVLNode * & root, AVLNode * A)
{
    AVLNode * B = A->left, * C = B->right, * p = A->up;

    B->right = C->left;
    if(B->right) B->right->up = B;

    A->left = C->right;
    if(A->left) A->left->up = A;

    C->right = A;
    C->left = B;
    A->up = B->up = C;
    C->up = p;

    if(p)
    {
        if(p->left == A) p->left = C;
        else p->right = C;
    }
    else root = C;

    if(C->bf ==  1) A->bf = -1;
    else A->bf = 0;
    if(C->bf == -1) B->bf =  1;
    else B->bf = 0;

    C->bf = 0;
}

void insertAVL(AVLNode * & root, int k, long long d)
{
    AVLNode * w,* p,* r;
    bool t, addLeaf;

    w = new AVLNode;        // tworzymy dynamicznie nowy węzeł
    w->left = w->right = w->up = NULL;
    w->key  = k;
    w->bf  = 0;
    w->data = d;
    w->leaves = 0;

    //----------------------------------------
    // FAZA 1 - wstawienie węzła do drzewa AVL
    //----------------------------------------

    p = root;              // rozpoczynamy od korzenia

    if(!p)
    {
        root = w;
    }       // jeśli drzewo jest puste, to węzeł w umieszczamy w korzeniu
    else
    {
        // inaczej szukamy miejsce dla w
        while(true){
            if(k < p->key)     // porównujemy klucze
            {
                if(!p->left)     // jeśli p nie posiada lewego syna, to
                {
                    p->left = w;   // lewym synem p staje się węzeł w
                    break;         // wychodzimy z pętli
                }
                p = p->left;     // inaczej przechodzimy do lewego syna
            }
            else
            {
                if(!p->right)    // jeśli p nie posiada prawego syna, to
                {
                    p->right = w;  // prawym synem staje się węzeł w
                    break;         // wychodzimy z pętli
                }
                p = p->right;    // inaczej przechodzimy do prawego syna
            }
            }

        w->up = p;           // ojcem w jest p

        //---------------------------------
        // FAZA 2 - równoważenie drzewa AVL
        //---------------------------------

        if(p->bf)
        {
            p->bf = 0; // UWAGA NR 1
        }
        else
        {
            if(p->left == w)   // UWAGA NR 2
                p->bf = 1;
            else
                p->bf = -1;

            r = p->up;        // będziemy szli w górę drzewa w kierunku korzenia
            // r i p wskazują ojca i syna na tej ścieżce
            t = false;
            while(r)
            {
                if(r->bf)
                {
                    t = true;     // ustalamy wynik pętli
                    break;        // przerywamy pętlę
                };
                // inaczej modyfikujemy r.bf
                if(r->left == p) r->bf =  1;
                else             r->bf = -1;
                p = r;          // przechodzimy w górę na wyższy poziom
                r = r->up;
            }

            if(t)             // jeśli r.bf = +/- 1, to musimy
            {
                // równoważyć drzewo
                if(r->bf == 1)
                {
                    if(r->right == p) r->bf = 0;  // gałęzie się równoważą
                    else if(p->bf == -1) LR(root,r);
                    else {
                    LL(root,r);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // r.bf = -1
                    if(r->left == p) r->bf = 0;  // gałęzie się równoważą
                    else if(p->bf == 1) RL(root,r);
                    else {
                    RR(root,r);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

AVLNode * findAVL(AVLNode * p, int k)
{
    while(p && p->key != k)
        p = (k < p->key) ? p->left: p->right;

    return p;
}

void DFSRelease(AVLNode * v)
{
    if(v)
    {
        DFSRelease(v->left);   // usuwamy lewe poddrzewo
        DFSRelease(v->right);  // usuwamy prawe poddrzewo
        delete v;              // usuwamy sam węzeł
    }
}

AVLNode * predAVL(AVLNode * p)
{
    AVLNode * r;

    if(p)
    {
        if(p->left)
        {
            p = p->left;
            while(p->right) p = p->right;
        }
        else
            do
            {
                r = p;
                p = p->up;
            }
            while(p && p->right != r);
    }
    return p;
}

AVLNode * removeAVL(AVLNode * & root, AVLNode * x)
{
    AVLNode  *t,*y,*z;
    bool nest;

    if(x->left && x->right)
    {
        y    = removeAVL(root,predAVL(x));
        nest = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(x->left)
        {
            y = x->left;
            x->left = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            y = x->right;
            x->right = NULL;
        }
        x->bf = 0;
        nest  = true;
    }

    if(y)
    {
        y->up    = x->up;
        y->left  = x->left;
        if(y->left)  y->left->up  = y;
        y->right = x->right;
        if(y->right)  y->right->up = y;
        y->bf    = x->bf;
    }

    if(x->up)
    {
        if(x->up->left == x) x->up->left = y;
        else x->up->right = y;
    }
    else root = y;

    if(nest)
    {
        z = y;
        y = x->up;
        while(y)
        {
            if(!y->bf)
            {
                // Przypadek nr 1
                if(y->left == z)  y->bf = -1;
                else y->bf = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if(((y->bf == 1) && (y->left == z)) || ((y->bf == -1) && (y->right == z)))
                {
                    // Przypadek nr 2
                    y->bf = 0;
                    z = y;
                    y = y->up;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(y->left == z)  t = y->right;
                    else t = y->left;
                    if(!t->bf)
                    {
                        // Przypadek 3A
                        if(y->bf == 1) LL(root,y);
                        else RR(root,y);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(y->bf == t->bf)
                    {
                        // Przypadek 3B
                        if(y->bf == 1) LL(root,y);
                        else RR(root,y);
                        z = t;
                        y = t->up;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Przypadek 3C
                        if(y->bf == 1) LR(root,y);
                        else RL(root,y);
                        z = y->up;
                        y = z->up;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Because bookkeeping will be very expensive while rebalancing, there are probably enough cases where it is more efficient to just count the leaves when needed (which in most cases isn't that interesting)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. I'm just holding number of NULLs under every node. It's easier to update. Do you know how to find index of Node with number of leaves under node?